# Get AngularJs $scope in History popstate event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am newbie angularjs developer. I have,

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('ProductCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function ($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.products = myapp.products;
    $scope.pager = $sce.trustAsHtml(myapp.pager);
    $scope.getProducts = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        var $link = $($event.target);
        var url = $event.target.href;
        $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.products = response.products;
                $scope.pager = $sce.trustAsHtml(response.pager);
            });
            history.pushState(response, "Index", url);
        });
    };
}]);
$(window).bind("popstate", function (e) {
    console.log(e.originalEvent.state);// I need scope here
});
```

You can see that clicking will call `getProducts` methods which will update $scope.products and  $scope.pager. I am also doing `history.pushState`. Now, what I want, whenever user click the back button, I need to update `$scope.products` and  `$scope.pager` again. Is that possible with AngularJS?

Comment: You should not be injecting HTML to create the pager, you should be doing it with angular instead.

Comment: You should not be using JQuery ajax($.get) you should be using $http instead

Comment: You should not  be call $event.preventDefault() since it is an angular method

Comment: You should not be calling  $scope.$apply inside an angular method if the method belongs to the scope angular will take care of it

Comment: @Dalorzo, can you update my code?

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and Angular ...don't do that!  That's only acceptable if you're trying to incorporate Angular into existing legacy code.  User proper separation of concerns ... controllers are meant ONLY for writing to $scope.  Create a service for backend calls an directives for DOM manipulation.

Comment: @mortsahl, please let me know what should I do with this code

Comment: @mortsahl, show me an example please

Comment: There are excellent tutorials on YouTube from egghead.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing `Jquery` and `Angularjs`. Now this can and often has been done as many useful libraries require `Jquery`.

But you are recreating **a lot** of Angular's functionality with Jquery here.

Firstly you should look at Angular's [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) and [`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider) which will enable your app navigation and history really easily.
Here is a [good blog post](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) to start with on this topic by Scotch.io.

Next up you are using Jquery's `Ajax`, instead use Angular's [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) inside a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), which when used in a Single Page Application (explained in the above post) will allow your entire data to be persisted across page reloads (which become template swaps).

In general, go through the entire [AngularJS Tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) and look at **how you can apply it's methodology to your app**. It will save you a lot of time, as Angular is well thought out and deals with all of these issues you are trying to tackle right now. It does have a steep learning curve but persevere. You can always leave out the test driven development(which they push in the tutorial) for now and focus on the core concepts and features.

Also look at this popular post on moving from Jquery to Angular, it may help: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 0):

For now I am fixing this using,

```
var $scope = angular.element('[ng-controller=ProductCtrl]').scope();
```

until I learn more.