# How to get current $sce outside controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For getting current $scope outside controller I can use,

```
 var $scope = angular.element('[ng-controller=ProductCtrl]').scope();
```

How to get the current controllers $sce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$sce` is a service so you can access it using the injector:

```
var elem = angular.element('[ng-controller=ProductCtrl]');
console.log("$scope: ",elem.scope());
console.log("$sce: ",elem.injector().get('$sce'));
```

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/8dfnH/1/)

Comment: can you check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459268/get-angularjs-scope-in-history-popstate-event

Answer (score 0):

Better use a service to pass data between controllers or other services. Services act like a Singleton.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12009408/3576459) is an example

Answer (score 0):

For now my fix is,

```
window.trustAsHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml
```